# Question(s) about PHP PDO connections

Tags: object-oriented, php, mysql

Let's say I have a Db class [ db.php ] :

```
<?php

    class Db
    {

        // class properties
        private $db_driver = ''; // dsn credentials
        private $db_dhost = '';
        private $db_dname = '';
        private $db_uname = '';
        private $db_pword = '';

        private $db_tzone = ''; // timezone

        private $db_email = ''; // error reporting
        private $db_headr = '';
        private $db_ecode = 0;
        private $db_emess = '';

        private $bConnected = false;
        private $conn = null;

        public function __construct($my_env) {

            # d = development, t = testing, p = production, s = sandbox
            $my_letter = strtoupper($my_env);

            $this->db_driver = 'mysql';
            $this->db_dhost = '...';
            $this->db_dname = '...';
            $this->db_uname = '...';
            $this->db_pword = '...';

            $this->db_tzone = 'America/Los_Angeles';

            $this->db_email = 'itmanager@myemail.com';
            $this->db_headr = 'From: system@myemail.com';

            // set db type, host and db credentials from $_SERVER environment variables
            // $this->db_driver = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'DB_' . $my_letter . '_DRIVER', FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
            // $this->db_dhost = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'DB_' . $my_letter . '_DHOST', FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
            // $this->db_dname = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'DB_' . $my_letter . '_DNAME', FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
            // $this->db_uname = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'DB_' . $my_letter . '_UNAME', FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
            // $this->db_pword = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'DB_' . $my_letter . '_PWORD', FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);            

        }

        public function dbConnect(){

            # initialize connection
            $this->conn = null;

            try {

                # Set default timezone
                date_default_timezone_set($this->db_tzone);

                # Set database options
                $db_options = array(
                    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
                    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                    PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT => 150,
                    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8mb4',
                    1002 => 'SET NAMES utf8mb4'
                )

                # Create new connection
                $this->conn = new PDO($db_driver . ':host=' . $this->db_dhost . ';dbname=' . $this->db_dname . ';charset=utf8mb4', 
                    $this->db_uname, 
                    $this->db_pword, 
                    $db_options);

                # Charset ignored < PHP 5.3.6
                $this->conn->exec('set names utf8');

                # set connected to true
                $bConnected = true;

            } catch (PDOException $de) {

                # get error information
                $this->db_ecode = $de->getCode();
                $this->db_emess = $de->getMessage();

                $body = '[' . $this->db_ecode . '] [' . $this->db_emess . ']';

                # send error to admin
                mail($this->db_email, "Database Connection Error", $body, $this->db_headr);

                # set connection to false
                $this->conn = null;

                # set connected to false
                $bConnected = false;

            }

            returned array($this->conn, $bConnected);

        }

    }


?>
```

To instantiate, I am using something similar to :

```
// include db class
include_once 'db.php';

// use development db
$instance = new Db('d');

// capture result of attempt
list($conn, $bConnected) = $instance->dbConnect();

if($bConnected == true) {

    // perform crud
    $conn = ...

}
```

My questions are this :

(a) is there a better way to abstract DSN connection credentials other than as $_SERVER variables

(b) can I improve upon this sample code, to make it more secure?

(c) should I implement cleanup code such as ...

```
$conn = null;
```

or ...

```
unset($conn);
```

if there is no exception occurring? And finally ...

(d) have I overlooked anything blatantly obvious?

Comment: There's no need to do the list().  You can return the instance itself, and check for null.  That simplifies the expression a bit.

Comment: Something similar to if(!$conn) {...or would it be better to use if($connect==null) {...?

Comment: Yep, either works.  Alternatively return true/false, and remove direct access to the instance, instead adding a query() method to the db class.  So its `if ($connected) { $db->query("...")}`

Comment: Even though this question is a year and a half old, it would be a good candidate for a [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

**a)** Don't really understand why you're using `$_SERVER` variable... I'm always passing `localhost` (or whatever) from static config.

**b)** Personally I'm using MySQLi, but my connection functions aren't that much different. Never heard about the need or way to make it more secure. It's already very secure as far as I'm aware. You can use SSL if you're connecting to remote server.

**c)** Check: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

So it depends on whether or not you want to have persistent connection.

Comment: My understanding is that use of MySQLi was being discouraged in favor of PHP PDO. That is why I am trying to best facilitate PDO using secure methods of accessing db credentials. So far, most of what I am seeing people encourage is (a) performing an fopen() on a config file outside of the web root structure, (b) use of $_SERVER environment variables and having the credentials buried in either the PHP.ini or httpd.conf and finally hosting the credentials on a completely different server. As for persistent connections, I want to see what other people encourage as I am uncertain whether they work

Comment: I've read that both MySQLi and PDO will be supported in upcoming PHP versions so I chose MySQLi on random, but maybe things changed... Well I always keep my config outside any web-accessed folder (and other includes as well, in root I got only index.php), but this method with `$_SERVER` sounds interesting, I'm gonna check it out. As for persistency, I've read that it depends on what website you are running. If you have lots of different visitors it suppose to be better not to have too many open connections.

Comment: Did a ilittle research and found that MySQLi might perform slightly better and since I don't need "Named Parameters" I'm gonna stick with it. It's still planned to supports it for many upcoming years. Read about that `$_SERVER` idea... lot's of people say it's not good. I have couple scripts that dumps `print_r($_SERVER)` just for me or `phpinfo()` somewhere... There's a nice idea however to keep your config encoded with a key, that's stored in let's say `$_SERVER['key']` and if you don't expose the key, your credtentials will be safer.

Comment: So basically create a config file with the creds (outside the web folder...) and fopen() on that. $_SERVER is used for the location of the config file?

Comment: No, `$_SERVER['key']` would be used for decrypting config file. There are couple methods... I think the least requiring is PHP's built-in `openssl_decrypt()` (and of course `openssl_encrypt()`). I'm using it for second layer of encrypting request body (HTML/JSON), besides SSL and it works very efficiently, would be good for reading config thousands of times.

Comment: @JohnEdwardLaw from what I understand the "advantage" to PDO is that you can use the same syntax for multiple different db server types - http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.drivers.php .